# Data in Array from N Textboes using For loop

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, textbox

There are "N" number of Textboxes on a Form,

I want to get the values in the textboxes in an Array.

using "For" loop,

Can any help me out with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all the controls on a form by calling this.Controls and loop through those comparing the control to a TextBox, when it is a TextBox you add the value to the array you are mentioning.

I'd use something like this:

```
List<string> values = new List<string>();
foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if(c is TextBox)
    {
        /*I didnt need to cast in my intellisense, but just in case!*/
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)c;
        values.Add(tb.Text);
    }
 }
 string[] array = values.ToArray();
```

Comment: `Control` doesn't have a `Text` property, I think you need to use `as` instead of `is` and check for `!= null`.

Comment: Well, i typed it in VS2005 real quick and intellisense said it had .Text property... i was suprised aswell to be honest. I'll edit in the line needed to fix it!

Comment: thanks i will workk on as you said, and i tried over with this code but didnt worked out.....

Comment: What exactly didn't work? I edited in a cast as Graham commented. Please try with this cast.

Comment: Thanks Kate, It really worked out...my textboxes are placed into Panel1>Panel2>TableLayoutpanel....<br>Thanks Man

Comment: @Rafee: The only thing is that using `is` and the `(TextBox)` cast means casting is happening twice. What would be better is to change `if(c is TextBox)...` to `var tb = c as TextBox; if(tb != null) { values.Add(tb.Text); }`. Then you only have one cast.

Comment: @Graham: I will try out for this option too, reduces the casting and and also avoiding null values tooo.......